# Refreshing jQm header after dynamically adding a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to dynamically add a button to a jQueryMobile header (this will be a login/logout).

The issue I'm having is - the button is not getting the jQm styling.
I tried using `.trigger("pagecreate")` and other options but nothing worked.

How should I refresh/reset/rebuild the header for the jQm style to take effect?

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mroh1w9v

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're just missing:

```
$('#homePage').trigger('pagecreate');
```

or

```
$('#homePage').trigger('create');
```

The result differs slightly

http://jsfiddle.net/mroh1w9v/2/